# how to use numpy.gradient working for left and right differences?

Tags: python, numpy

how to use numpy.gradient working for left and right. It works by default for central difference.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
    slice1[axis] = slice(1, -1)
    slice2[axis] = slice(2, None)
    slice3[axis] = slice(None, -2)
    # 1D equivalent -- out[1:-1] = (f[2:] - f[:-2])/2.0
```

By:

```
    slice1[axis] = slice(1, -1)
    slice2[axis] = slice(1, -1)
    slice3[axis] = slice(None, -2)
    # 1D equivalent -- out[1:-1] = (f[1:-1] - f[:-2])
```

for left differences and by:

```
    slice1[axis] = slice(1, -1)
    slice2[axis] = slice(2, None)
    slice3[axis] = slice(1, -1)
    # 1D equivalent -- out[1:-1] = (f[2:] - f[1:-1])
```

for the right one in the `numpy.gradient()` function. And remove `/2.0` in the statement:

```
    out[slice1] = (f[slice2] - f[slice3])/2.0
```